# xampp apache not starting at all

Tags: xampp

I did get this error before, that the host was wrong.  I did  change httpd-sll.conf

```
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName localhost
```

```
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:51:21 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forumster code here
```

But now when I start apache, it only give this error, and there is nothing in the logs.

I did try to see what is in Windows Event Viewer, but do not know what to look for.

The apache port is 80 and ssl port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.
Did uninstall xampp and re install it.